# How to check if a file is stored on the SD Card using MediaStore?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mediastore

I made an audio player app and I'm using mediastore queries to load the audio files. I can group them by folder but now I want to render the files stored on the SD Card in a different way. I could not find any way to get this info. I noticed that the Files app from stock Android displays a small SDCard icon for the audio files located on the card.. so it is definitely possible to do it.

Comment: You can/should do it differently. On Android 10+ you can list the files on primary volume and removable micro sd card separately.

Comment: For below Android 19 the .DATA column will give you full path and hence you can see if it is on removable media.